# AJAX having issues with sending data through xhr.send()?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/) code to upload and display images.
Javascript is as follows...

```
xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
```

And here is my PHP

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);

if ($fn) {

    // AJAX call
    file_put_contents(
        'uploads/' . $fn,
        file_get_contents('php://input')
    );
    echo "$fn uploaded";
    exit();

}
else {

    // form submit
    $files = $_FILES['fileselect'];

    foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
        if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $fn = $files['name'][$id];
            move_uploaded_file(
                $files['tmp_name'][$id],
                'uploads/' . $fn
            );
            echo "<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

The problem that I'm having is that I want to also send an id for the posting along with the image file in order to update my tables. It would be great if I could do something like this...

```
xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(file + "fname=david");
```

But I am fully aware that I can't send two types of data in the same send. What is the best way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do file uploads with `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, it has to be `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: when I change that I get the error... <b>Warning</b>: "Missing boundary in multipart/form-data Post data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b>

Comment: You can't just change the header, you actually have to format the data properly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData